# Errors appear when using rxjs in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I downloaded rxjs via with following command:

```
npm install @reactivex/rxjs
```

in the folder src contains many ts files:
[image]

Then I copied the src folder into my project based on asp.net core as:
[image]

Then Visual Studio compiler complains a lot of things:
[image]

The `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What's your tsconfig.json look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to target ES6 in your `tsconfig.json` file. 
tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6"
}
```

Or, you may need to install a polyfill that handles Promises (and more) and has typings for Typescript, like core-js.

```
npm install typings core-js
typings install –global –save dt~core-js
```

Comment: You are right, instead of ES5 I changed it to ES6. Thanks so much. What is core-js?

Comment: ES5 is an older, widely supported version of Javascript. ES6 is newer and, depending on your target audience, they may not be able to run ES6 code. If you look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises you can see that your code will not work in IE, Opera, Chrome <= 29, Android <= 4.4, etc. Core-JS is a javascript library that fills the gap on many ES6 features (like Promises), but in ES5 code. So, if you need to, you can target ES5 and use Core-JS to be able to use ES6 features while still ending up with code that will run on older browsers.

Comment: After:
`npm install typings core-js
typings install –global –save dt~core-js `

You can add:
Add this line to the main .ts
`/// <reference path="../../typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />`